# Closing a miniaturized NSWindow and later restoring it

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I noticed that the sequence:

```
setReleasedWhenClosed(false)
miniaturize
close
makeKeyAndOrderFront
```

results in a visible window for which *hovering* on the standard
titlebar butons doesn't work (clicking on the buttons and
moving/resizing the window does work).

The problem is the miniaturize call, without it the window restores
correctly. But I need to be able to hide a miniaturized window and
later restore it.

Any known workarounds?

Background story:

I want to implement the `hide` functionality on my windows. `orderOut`
doesn't cut it because it doesn't work on a miniaturized window (known
bug from 2008), so `close` is the next thing. But I can't seem to
restore a closed window that was closed while miniaturized, without
this weird bug.

Thanks,
Cosmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to set setOneShot(true).